# Concat data frame not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, concatenation

I have two data frames df1 and df2. both have same numbers of rows but different columns.
I want to concat all columns of df1 and 2nd and 3rd column of df2.

df1 has 119 columns and df2 has 3 of which i want 2nd & 3rd

Code I am using is:

```
data_train_test = pd.concat([df1,df2.iloc[:, 
[2,3]]],axis=1,ignore_index=False)
```

Error I am getting is

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (121, 39880), indices imply (121, 28898)
```

My Analysis:

```
39880 - 28898 = 10982
```

df1 is TFID data frame made from concat of two other data frames with rows 17916+10982 = 28898.

how I made df2 is

```
frames = [data, prediction_data]
df2 = pd.concat(frames)
```

I am not able to find the exact reason for this problem. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it by resetting the index while creating df2.

```
frames = [data, prediction_data]
df2 = pd.concat(frames).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your question correctly but I thinks what you want to do is :

```
data_train_test = pd.concat([df1,df2[[1,2]]])
```

`.iloc[]` is used to select a row (the ith row in the index of your dataframe). So you don't really need it their.

Comment: I tried that but it gave me same error plus concat without axis = 1 parameter will try to append the data and I want it join horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'b1':[1], 'b2':[2], 'b3':[3]})

data_train_test = pd.concat([df1,df2[df2.columns[1:3]]], axis=1)
# or
data_train_test = pd.concat([df1,df2.loc[:,df2.columns[1:3]]], axis=1)
```